# vba - need logic for back order

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using a query on **Access**, even though I have created this reference on Excel,
[image]

And currently my VBA program is importing only `regular orders`. 
I'd like to make both regular-orders and back-order import works. But when it comes to Back-order, things gets tricky. Mostly because we never put shipping dates.

As in the image, there are some scenarios

1)  2 orders of Product `A`,

a.  Order A_1 gets shipped full quantity

b.  Order A_2 gets backordered

2)  1 orders of Product `B`, gets full shipping

3)  1 orders of Product `C`, half of it gets shipped while the other is back-ordered.

This is how my program distinguish orders in detail:

1) If the quantity is 0, delete columns and don't get imported 
On query design, My quantity is [Quantity Ordered] - [Quantity Backordered]

Ex)   Order A_1 200  - 0     =    200

Order A_2 200 -   200     =    0

2) Imports today’s order only

*note* 1) [Quantity-Shipped] gets updated few days later which is of no use to me.

2)  Every order has unique order number

Updated:

My fields for OrderHistoryHeader tables

SalesOrderNo, OrderDate, OrderStatus, CustomerNo, CustomerPONo, EmailAddress, LastInvoiceDate, LastInvoiceNumber, SalespersonNo, NonTaxableAmt, DateCreated, TimeCreated, TimeUpdated

for OrderHistoryDetail tables

SalesOrderNo, SequenceNo, LineKey, ItemCode, ItemType, ItemCodeDesp, PromiseDate, QuantityOrdered, QuantityShipped, QuantityBackOrdered, OriginalUnitPrice, LastUnitPrice

For query, I have to put fields based on the qualification of the system to import,
and I just pull necessary fields from the Tables

Comment: Aside from being thoroughly confused (I see three A orders, not two; two C orders, not one; and I have no idea what A_1 and A_2 are supposed to refer to), what is your question?

Comment: @PaulAbbott One of A (out of two) got backordered, which means they got divided into two. So is the C as well

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks for your reply. I was hoping to import the divided orders, not creating any duplicate of the existing regular orders! Hope it makes sense!

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing the table layouts and your current SQL. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41515459/edit) to include them.

Comment: @Comintern Since the access tables/queries have customer information, I don't think I can update them here. I believe the table image above is enough.. ?? If not, please specify what other tables that you need! I will try my best to upload them

Comment: The data isn't necessary - just the fields in question.  More important is the query you're using.

Comment: @Comintern just updated!! thank you!